# How to implement numbering sequence in java

Tags: java, ms-word, swt

I am working on SWT application, I have the functionality to implement MS Word numbering sequence in my application.

At any time user can modify the existing sequence, so that whole structure should adjust accordingly and I should save that in database.

Please look at the above screen shot.

I am thinking about the string manipulation. But seems to its not the optimal one. Please suggest me the best way...

I am able to create the tree structure, like parent child relation. My question is how to implement numbering sequence, if user changes the level how to adjust the whole tree?

User has the possibility to change the number sequence like

Before increasing level

```
  1.    Main chapter 1
  1.1.  Sub chapter1
  1.2.  Sub chapter 2
  2.    Main chapter 2
```

Status after increasing the level

```
    1.  Mian chapter 1
    1.1.    Sub chapter 2
    2.  Sub chapter 1
    3.  Main chapter 2
```

Similarly user can decrease the level also.

Comment: As you can see from your task, the data model is `tree`. You have root node, and child nodes, connected to the root node, grandchild nodes, connected to their parent nodes and so on. Implement this data model in your application and build numbers according to the location of every node.

Comment: It'll be helpful if you can show some code on what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Given that a table of contents mimics a tree structure, you can do a linked list of `Node` objects like so,

```
class Node {
    int index;
    String text;
    Node next;
    Node contents;
}
```

Then, you can have something that looks like this:

```
head ->  [1|"Main Chapter 1"](1) -> [2|"Main Chapter 2"](2) -> ...
                 ^                       ^
                 |                       |
                 |               [1|"Sub Chapter 2.1"](2.1) -> [2|"Sub Chapter 2.2"](2.2) -> ...
                 |
         [1|"Sub Chapter 1.1"](1.1) -> [2|"Sub Chapter 1.2"](1.2) -> ...
                                          ^
                                          |
                                     [1|"Sub Chapter 1.2.1"](1.2.1) -> ...
```

`next` will be used to keep track of other `Node`s at the same level 
`contents` will be used to keep track of the children `Node`s at the lower level

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at the [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) Pattern. It allows you to treat groups of elements like individual elements. The basic structure is a tree that contains single nodes or lists of nodes, you can use that to generate the numbering based on tree and list position.